# What is the Windows "WorkerW" windows and what creates them?

Tags: windows, user-interface, winapi

On some Windows 10 computers (and possibly older versions) there are sometimes "WorkerW" windows that show up in the list from a call to EnumWindows.  This is not on all computers - just some.  What are these windows and what creates them?

Comment: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/119783-desktop-class-workerw/ many more such posts, use web search

Comment: `WorkerW` is just an arbitrary window [class name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-window-classes#class-name). **Any** module can register a window class with that name. This question is not answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is basically created by calling Shell API function SHCreateWorkerWindowW. W stands for widechar (unicode) version of the window vs. SHCreateWorkerWindowA for ascii version. Any application that needs to listen to window messages call this Api to create a worker window. The API is basically a wrapper around CreateWindowEx but with window class name that is hardcoded to "WorkerW" or "WorkerA".

Comment requested to provide supporting documentation. Unfortunately, there is no documentation on MSDN because this is an undocumented function. If you look at the disassembly of SHCreateWorkerWindowA in shlwapi.dll you can verify this easily. Alternatively, you can do a GetProcAddress() for SHCreateWorkerWindowA and call the function to create the worker window.

Comment: A link to the function at MSDN or some sort of supporting documentation would improve this answer.

Comment: Thanks Nabie.  We are thinking that one such process that creates WorkerW might be the windows desktop background slideshow.  Is this a possibility?

Comment: `WorkerW` is just an arbitrary, legal window class name. **Any** module can register a window class with that name, and create instances of it. This is really just a poor answer to a poor question.

Comment: @dc_ucw it is quite possible that desktop background slideshow creates this window. It would be easy to find out by enumerating the process that creates this window and then loading the process in dependency viewer. The dependency viewer utility will show you if a call to this function is made.